# How do I properly dispose SMTP object?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have a loop where if you dropped a file into a folder, it would email you on success/failure. I tried the 'using' statement which implements Dispose() automatically.

I also tried a 'try/finally' statement (recommended here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement . Both of which gave me this error:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name 'system.net.mail.smtpclient'

Attempt 1:

```
private int _disposed;
        private readonly string _fromEmail;
        private readonly SmtpClient _client;

public Emailer()
        {
            _disposed = 0;
            _fromEmail = "email";
            _client = new SmtpClient("domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com", 25)
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_fromEmail, "password")
            };
        }

public async Task SendEmailAsync(IList<string> to, string subject, string body)
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress(_fromEmail);
                foreach (string toEmail in to)
                    mail.To.Add(toEmail);
                
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                using (SmtpClient smtp = _client)
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = _client.Credentials;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = _client.EnableSsl;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
                }
            }
        }
```

Attempt 2:

```
private int _disposed;
        private readonly string _fromEmail;
        private readonly SmtpClient _client;

public Emailer()
        {
            _disposed = 0;
            _fromEmail = "email";
            _client = new SmtpClient("domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com", 25)
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_fromEmail, "password")
            };
        }

public async Task SendEmailAsync(IList<string> to, string subject, string body)
        {
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress(_fromEmail);
                foreach (string toEmail in to)
                    mail.To.Add(toEmail);
                
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                try
                {
                    SmtpClient smtp = _client;
                    smtp.Credentials = _client.Credentials;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = _client.EnableSsl;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

My Dispose() Method

```
public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _disposed, 1, 0) != 0)
                return;

            _client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line specifically throws the Exception?

Comment: Where are you instantiating _client?  My guess is that when you get to this line `using (SmtpClient smtp = _client)`, the _client variable has already been disposed.

Comment: await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail); throws the exception the second time around

Comment: @PeterG I'm instantiating it in the constructor with the following: _client = new SmtpClient("domain-com.mail.protection.outlook.com", 25)
            {
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email", "password")
            };

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, instead of just a few lines out of context. The [mre] should include where you're instantiating the `_client`, rather than adding that information in a comment. You need to [edit] your post to add the [mre].

Comment: I've edited it to be minimal, it's just missing the class name.

Comment: In your first attempt, the `using` will dispose the `SmtpClient`, so you can't use it a second time. In your second attempt, you explicitly dispose everything. No need for either of those to happen.

Comment: @DavidG I got rid of both **using** statements and ended it off with a dispose function but I get the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing a Smtp object on your first call. You need to expose method to dispose smtp object and once your loop gets complete call this method to dispose your smtp object and get rid of your using statement.

```cs
public void DisposeSMTPClient()
{
    _client.Dispose();
}

public async Task SendEmailAsync(IList<string> to, string subject, string body)
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage();
            
                mail.From = new MailAddress(_fromEmail);
                foreach (string toEmail in to)
                    mail.To.Add(toEmail);
                
                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                    await _client.SendMailAsync(mail);
            
        }
```

Call `DisposeSMTPClient` this function after your loops end

Answer (score -1):

My problem was using 2 `using` statements.

I fixed it by using a try catch block for sending the email and the original `using` statement along with implementing the IDisposable class.

```
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress(_fromEmail);
                foreach (string toEmail in to)
                    mail.To.Add(toEmail);

                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("D:\\TestFile.txt"));//--Uncomment this to send any attachment  
                try
                {
                    SmtpClient smtp = _client;
                    smtp.Credentials = _client.Credentials;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = _client.EnableSsl;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(mail);
                }
                catch
                { }
            }
```

Comment: This is a terrible approach. Not only are you blindly swallowing all Exceptions that might happen in that `try` block, you aren't handling proper disposal of the `SmtpClient` (unless I'm missing something - which is certainly possible, or that happens elsewhere in code that was not posted here). Some of the comments on your question addressed the *actual* issue. All this does is ignore the larger problem.

Comment: I've implemented IDisposable with it's Disposable function. I've also added an exception handler that will log any problems and send them to me directly. I left the catch block empty for simplicity sake.